# Error with ibatis sql iterate

Tags: ibatis

I'm using ibatis + DWR , but when i pass a map to ibatis i will get an error as below:

> Cause: com.ibatis.sqlmap.client.SqlMapException: ParameterObject or
>   property was not a Collection, Array or Iterator.

here is my sql:

```
<update id="updateDarenFlagByUserTagIDs" parameterClass="java.util.Map">
    update system_usertag 
    set isdaren = 1
    where uid = #uid# 
    <isNotEmpty prepend=" AND " property="utidlist">
        and utid in
        <iterate open="(" close=")" conjunction="," property="utidlist">
          #utidlist[]#
        </iterate>
    </isNotEmpty>
</update>
```

and here in the DWR part, i passed a map as below:

```
{'uid':uid, 'utidlist':utidlist}
```

Any ideas on this error?

Answer (score 0):

I have answered the exact same question in the following post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18997883/malformed-url-exception-in-ibatis/19025819#19025819 do make reference to it. The solution to your problem is very simple, ensure that the argument nested in your iterate tag `<iterate></iterate>` which in your case is "**utidlist**" is indeed a list/collection and nothing but a list. The cause of this error is that your iterable property "**utidlist**" isn't a list. If you can get it to be a list and not a flat value you'll just be fine.

Just in case you can still get it to work you may also want to paste a full stack of your logs so that you can see what is going wrong.